# R character value is null, but fails is.null() test

Tags: r

Very strange error on a value being not null, but is claimed to be null, even though it evaluates to FALSE on is.null() test. See below. In this case, pid seems to be null, but the test fails, causing me all sorts of 'next step' problems in the code.

```
> pid <- system2('ps', args = "-ef | grep 'ssh -f' | grep -v grep | tr -s ' ' | \ cut -d ' ' -f 3", stdout = TRUE)
> pid
character(0)
> is.null(pid)
[1] FALSE
> if(!is.null(pid) && nchar(pid)) {cat('got some pid')}
Error in if (!is.null(pid) && nchar(pid)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
> if(!is.null(pid)) {cat('got some pid? Really?')}
got some pid? Really?
```

What does folks think is happening here? Here is my version information of R:

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          2.2                         
year           2015                        
month          08                          
day            14                          
svn rev        69053                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
nickname       Fire Safety
```

Full version of the OS:

```
Linux rserver 3.16.0-44-generic #59~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 7 15:07:27 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

In the end, I simply want this code to run:

```
> if (nchar(pid) > 0) {
+     cat('do something\n')
+ }
Error in if (nchar(pid) > 0) { : argument is of length zero
```

Comment: `nchar()` does not return a logical value, it returns an integer value and in this case it is `integer(0)`.  For example with  `if(TRUE && nchar(character(0))) "a"` you get the same error `Error in if (TRUE && nchar(character(0))) "a" : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Comment: That should still evaluate to TRUE or FALSE depending on whether nchar(pid) is zero or greater. In my case, is.null(nchar(pid)) also says FALSE. In other words, output of nchar(pid) is not a null value. Changing to if (nchar(pid) > 0) {} does not change the error.

Comment: Being `NULL` and having length 0 are entirely different

Comment: You might want to change the `is.null(pid)` condition with `length(pid)==0` (as already implied in the comments above).

Answer (score 4):

The fact that you have an empty character variable doesn't mean that it's NULL. Here's an example:

```
pid <- character()
> pid
character(0)
> is.null(pid)
[1] FALSE
> pid <- NULL
> pid
NULL
> is.null(pid)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: So, what is the right check [if condition] for my code to run properly in this case? My if (nchar(pid) >0) {} still complains saying 'Error in if (nchar(pid) > 0) { : argument is of length zero'

Comment: Maybe you could try `length(pid)==0`. That should not throw an error, but return `TRUE` for an empty vector.

Comment: @user3949008 - I think you may want to use `length(x)`  in the `if()` statement.  If it evaluates to zero, it's false and true otherwise.  So you can safely do `!length(x)`